# React-Router Route from child Switch does not render component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have read on multiple threads here that Switch components can be present in multiple files without issue. However, my Route in a different component does not render its contents.

The situation is as follows:

**HOC Content component**

```
// I have a useHistory() variable exported from an external file, that variable is named history
onComplete = () => {
  history.push('/home')
}

// Consider that onComplete() is called properly and works.

return(
 <>
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/home' component={Home}  // Also tried with render props...
    </Switch>
 </>
)
```

**Home component**

```
useEffect(() => {
  history.push('/search')
}, [])

return(
 <>
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/search' component={Search}  // Also tried with render props...
    </Switch>
 </>
)
```

**Search component**

```
useEffect(() => {
  // This does not print, it does not reach.
  console.log('hey')
}, [])

return(
 <>
    <h1>Search component</h1>
 </>
)
```

I manage to reach the Home component and a console.log(..) in the useEffect hook gets printed. The route change then happens, my broswer displays localhost:3001/search in the address bar, but nothing is rendered on screen.

If I put the Search component in a Route in the Content component's Switch, the component is rendered,
Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Path for search will be /home/search .. beacuse of nested switch.
Try opening

```
localhost:3001/home/search
```

Comment: It does not seem to fix the issue I'm afraid. Path is fine as /home/search, but the component still does not render.